# How do widgets that put HTML in a HTML textbox (tags, Google+ Invite, etc) work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface

I find it hard to get myself started in this topic so I can write my own widgets for my own needs. How can I combine plain text and HTML elements (links, images), like seen everywhere on the web (Google, Facebook, etc), in a HTML textbox in a way that it still behaves all together like simple text (i. e. deleteable with backspace)?

How does this work? What is the underlying "trick"?

Comment: Are you talking about a Content Editor? > http://ckeditor.com/demo

Comment: @3rror404 a WYSIWYG editor would be the next step. For now I'd be happy with something like http://www.emposha.com/demo/fcbkcomplete_2/

Comment: To be clear: I don't want any plugin. I want to know how this stuff works at its core.

Comment: The source files are right there for you to look at: http://www.emposha.com/demo/fcbkcomplete_2/jquery.fcbkcomplete.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, your question indicates that you need a starting point,
lets then start with a basic HTML such as a `div`, a `ul`, and an `input`

```
<div class="myTags">
    <ul id="tags">
        <li class="nd"><input type="text" id="tagInput" placeholder="add some tags..."/></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

now lets write some jquery to handle the tagging:

```
$('#tagInput').keypress(function(e){
 if (e.keyCode === 13) {
     tag = $(this).val();
     if(tag.length > 0){
        var newLi = $('<li></li>').text(tag);
     }
     $('#tags').append(newLi);
     $(this).val('');
     }
});
```

this jquery snippet listens to the keypress event on the provided input which I called `tagInput`
the enter key goes with `keyCode 13` hence, if it is been hit you take the value of the textbox and and create a new li element then you go and append it to your ul.

what is missing here is how to make the ul looks like horizontal, this is a starting css to be used:

```
#tags{
    float: left;
    min-height: 10px;
    min-width: 100px;
    margin:0px;
    padding: 0px;
    list-style-type: none;    
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
#tags li { display: inline-block; padding: 10px;}
#tagInput{background: none;
    border: none;}
```

which will make the ul horizontal, and it will delete the background from the input and adds the border and the background to the ul, which is a lovely **trick** specially with the placeholder being available, Now for the backspace deleting process it is simple too, take the previous jquery snippet and add the following code to it:

```
$('#tagInput').keyup(function(e){
    if(e.keyCode === 8 && $(this).val().length<=0){
         $('#tags li:last').not('.nd').remove();
     }
});
```

which what it does is simply check for `keyCode 8` which is a backspace, **Note:** some people would recommend to listen to `keyCode 46` which is `delete`, it is up to you.
and I also check for the input value so it should be empty to delete the last inserted tag.
Now by wrapping it up you have the following [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/BcsRV/) to check.
which is a good start point so you can now do whatever you want with the tag styles and many other fancy stuff.

Hope that I helped.
**Disclaimer:** the previous code is not to be copy pasted, and it is there just for point clarification.

**Update**
also, adding `outline:0` to the input will make more real, see [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hPg3G/)

```
#tagInput{background: none;
    border: none; outline:0}
```

Comment: THIS is what I was looking for. Thank you! I've edited the fiddle the make it even more realistic: http://jsfiddle.net/hPg3G/1/

Comment: @prc322 - well sure, having the tags on the left is also awesome, you gave me an idea too, check this fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/jnnXN/

Answer (score 0):

This is all done through javascript (mostly). Look into jquery. All the heavy lifting is done and provides you with a "easy-to-use" javascript library for client-side scripting that can make all these things possible. Obliviously the more complicated you get, the more custom scripting will be needed.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to display both text and any other content (images) in one editable component (text area) that looks like native component. I think you can easily achieve that with CSS. The whole trick is to clear the default styling of `textarea` and wrap it with `<div>` with custom CSS.

See an example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/NN4sE/)

You can further enhcance the solution with Javascript and CSS. For instance, you can make the `textarea` to auto expand [as you type](http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/)

Hope that helps!